# Episerver-Finding Parent Block in nested block

Tags: episerver

Is there a way in episerver to find parent block from a nested block?

For instance

Parent Block

1. Region (THis is IList)
2. Market(THis is IList)
3. Dept(THis is IList)
4. RegionContentArea

Region Block

1. Region (This will come from parent block)
2. MarketContentArea

Market Block

1. Market(This will come from parent block)
2. DeptContentArea

Dept Block

1. Dept (This will come from parent block)
2. Title & other properties

I tried using **GetReferencesToContent()** but this will work only for a single level hierarchy ie in the above case Region block.

```
var references = contentRepository.GetReferencesToContent(ownerContent.ContentLink, false).FirstOrDefault();

contentRepository.TryGet(references.OwnerID, references.OwnerLanguage, out ContentData owner);
```

If i use the same code for traversing through Market block ,it would give me Region block & not parent block. I know that there needs to be some looping around required but unable to get this as I am a newbie in episerver.
Please help.

Comment: Idea of block is reusability, so you (editor) create block once, and then use it in several places. With this concept, it is by design that a "child" block can have any number of "parents" on the data level. So you need somehow to maintain a context of specific "parent" when using children. For example, if you need this in view, you can add some value to viewcontext from controller of parent block, so child block can access it (if you use separate controller for every block); or render all the blocks only from the top-most parent controller, which will loop through children blocks etc.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you need to accomplish? As stated above, a shared block can be used in multiple locations. It "lives" inside an assets folder - it's parent content reference will in other words point to a folder.

When added to a `ContentArea` property, the property will simply hold a reference to a block instance, regardless of it's "true location".

The structure you describe is more of a logical one, it doesn't reflect the actual hiererchy of things in Episerver (since a Region block, for example, can be used in multiple locations).

Comment: As mentioned in the example above,i need to achieve this to get the reference within nested block. I am aware that contentareas are used to just hold the reference to the block but I also know that these blocks that i have created will not be shared with any other blocks so the structure although logical will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This post on the <strike>Episerver</strike> Optimizely Forum may be helpful:

[How to get a reference to a parent block from current block](https://world.optimizely.com/forum/legacy-forums/Episerver-7-CMS/Thread-Container/2013/1/How-to-get-a-reference-to-a-parent-block-from-current-block/)